# How is the display in a view renamed?

Tags: views

When you make a copy of one of  displays of a view the new display is given a name like `Page 2`. How do you rename that display? I can't seem to find a way of renaming the pge but I suspect there must be a link to edit it.

I have done it before and wonder whether some module or CSS change may be occluding the link required to change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change its machine name their option available in advance option of view or want to change its display name that will change form display. [image]